# Why am I having trouble with CSS styles on mobile but not in dev tools responsive mode?

Tags: css, browser, responsive-design, cross-browser, google-chrome-devtools

I am having an issue on my mobile device with my CSS styles. For some reason, the styles look great when I'm inspecting them on dev tools using both an edge browser and chrome browser. But on my iPhone, the CSS styles aren't working properly, and it is just glitching. The styles are for a flashcard and when the user clicks on the flashcard, a class is added called flip which then flips that card over to show the other side of the flashcard. However, when I click on the card on my iPhone browser, rather than flipping over to show the other side it just glitches and then goes blank for the other side. I'm using React to toggle the flip style. I tried adding a media query but that didn't do anything. Here is my CSS code:

```
.card {
  border: 1px solid var(--light-gray-accent);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-inline: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  min-height: 350px;
  max-height: 500px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 150ms;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(var(--rotate-y, 0))
    translateY(var(--translate-y, 0));
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(var(--rotate-y, 0))
    translateY(var(--translate-y, 0));
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card:hover {
  --translate-y: -2px;
  scale: 1.05;
}

.card.flip {
  --rotate-y: 180deg;
}


.card .front,
.card .back {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1rem;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.card .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* testing out a strategy for iphone */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .card.flip {
    --translate-y: -2px;
    --rotate-y: 180deg;
  }

}

.card-edit {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I tried adding a media query but that didn't work. I also tried adding -webkit prefixes to the transforms and back-face visibility but that didn't work. I'm not sure why this code works in my dev tools but not on my iPhone browser. I would love some help as to why this wouldn't be working on my iPhone browser.

Comment: For us to help you, you'll need to edit your question to add a working [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/2518285) which demonstrates the problem. But you may be able use these [debugging techniques](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/2518285) to help yourself. Sounds like you have a Windows computer, so some of the options in this article won't be available to you.